# wrong written boolean method?

Tags: if-statement, boolean, operators

i have this problem with boolean method, description is in comments, but I don't get this: why is this "false" after brackets here? and how can I use if statement to see if condition is right or wrong inside return? I can't modify anything else, but these brackets. I'm totally confused.I understand the code below, first I have condition (a&&b) ? "then something" but in first code I don't get it. Here is my code:

```
public class Aufgabe5 {

    // returns true if (and only if) both x and y are in the range from 1 to 20 (including 1 and 20)
    // and x is larger than y.
    private static boolean inRangeAndOrdered(int x, int y) {
        return (false /* TODO: modify this expression */);
    }

    // returns 1 if both a and b are true, 0 if a differs from b, and -1 if both a and b are false
    private static int wiredLogic(boolean a, boolean b) {
        return (a && b ? (-1 /* TODO: modify this expression */) : (-1 /* TODO: modify this expression */)) +
               (a || b ? (-1 /* TODO: modify this expression */) : (-1/* TODO: modify this expression */));
    }
```

Comment: I thought this site was for beginners too, but as I can see, if it's not some super hard question : Let's downvote it! For what people? How should question look like to be upvoted? I'm stuck with these, and if it's easy for you, help. DON'T DOWNVOTE!

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer why `false` is after the brackets because I don't know why you have it there? Possibly its an odd requirement that you need. It sounds like you need the `false` to be there for some reason. However, this method would be easier to write and easier to understand without it.

The below method will achieve your requirements in the comments (while making use of the `false`).

```
// returns true if (and only if) both x and y are in the range from 1 to 20 (including 1 and 20)
// and x is larger than y.
private static boolean inRangeAndOrdered(int x, int y)
{
    return (false == !(x >= 1 && x <= 20 && y >= 1 && y <= 20));
}
```

What this return statement is doing:

First, `x >= 1 && x <= 20` will equate to `true` if x is greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 20.

Second, `y >= 1 && y <= 20` will equate to `true` if y is greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 20.

Then the results of both statements are combined using `&&` and wrapped in brackets. If both x and y are greater than or equal to 1 and less than or equal to 20 this will whole bracketed statement equates to `true`.

Adding the "not" keyword `!` before the brackets will reverse the boolean value. So if the bracketed statement equates to true it will be reversed to false.

Examples:

`true == !true = false` or `false == !false = false`

The return statement compares the reversed equated value of the bracketed statement `false == !({statement})`:

1. If `{statement}` = true, it is reversed to false, false equals false, true is returned.
2. If `{statement}` = false, it is reversed to true, true does not equal false, false is returned.

This return is essentially using an `if statement`. It can also be read as the following, however the code I mentioned above is short form:

```
if (false == !(x >= 1 && x <= 20 && y >= 1 && y <= 20))
    return true;
else
    return false;
```

The below method achieves the requirements in the comments of your second method:

```
// returns 1 if both a and b are true, 0 if a differs from b, and -1 if both a and b are false
private static int wiredLogic(boolean a, boolean b)
{
    return (a && b ? 1 : (a == b ? -1 : 0));
}
```

This return statement is doing three checks to meet the requirements:

1. If the combination of a and b is true then return 1.
2. If the combination of a and b is not true and a equals b then a and b are both false, return -1.
3. If the combination of a and b is not true and a does not equal b then either a is false and b is true or b is false and a is true, return 0.